# Gatling 2.1.6 stuck after many Request timed out

Tags: performance, scala, netty, gatling

### Scenario :

```
val limit = 100

val totalCount = 1000000

def testDisplay() = {
  scenario(scenarioName)
  .exec(get("/service/path")
  .queryParam("offset", _ => OffsetFeeder.nextOffset(totalCount, limit))
  .queryParam("limit", limit)
  .check(status is 200)
  .transformResponse {
      case response if response.statusCode.get >= 400 =>
        new ResponseWrapper(response) {
          val errorBody = response.body.string
          logger warn s"ErrorBody=$errorBody"
        }
    });
}
```

### Simulation :

```
setUp(testDisplay.inject(simpleRampUp))
```

### Gatling params :

- users = 10000
- duration = 45 min

### Actual behaviour

After some successful calls, gatling throw timeoutexception for the rest of calls (its OKay) like this :

```
17:55:29.035 [INFO ] i.g.h.a.AsyncHandler - Request 'display' failed for user 1993228817214452858-9536: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timed out to [host:port] of 60000 ms
```

After all timeoutexception thrown, gatling stuck at 36% and log only this (infinitely) :

```
================================================================================
2015-09-11 18:28:49                                        4634s elapsed
---- display ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[##########################------------------------------------------------] 36%
          waiting: 0      / active: 6364   / done:3636  
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=3636   KO=0     )
> display                                                  (OK=3636   KO=0     )
================================================================================
```

### Expect behaviour

I expect that gatling complete the run and all timeouted request will be treated as KO, but it stay logging, and don't complete.

Comment: any solution you found for this. I am running some performance scripts and running into exact same issue.

Comment: as of gatling 3.1 (at least) timeouts are treated as KO